# How to move chromium config from one PC to next?

Tags: configuration, chromium

I have a new laptop. The old was running Ubuntu 20.04 and the new Ubuntu 21.10.

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 21.10 (not an upgrade).

I want to transfer my Chromium config from the old to the new device.

With "config" I mean: Browser history, Passwords, autofill info like address, ...

What is the most simple way?

AFAIK I use Chromium via snap.

Comment: The easit way is just logging in with the same account, it should sync automatically. Other than that copy the hidden folder, as always.

Comment: @ChanganAuto AFAIK, Chromium does not support sync anymore.

Comment: Right. Copy over the folder then.

Comment: @ChanganAuto which folder should I copy?

Comment: The "chromium" folder inside .config (maybe different if snap)